# Rectifier and EMI filter for multiple led drivers

Tags: bridge-rectifier, emi-filtering

I try to make a power supply stage for 2 offline led drivers insted of making 2 different boards.
Find in atteched file the design A and B. Could you explain and suggest me what is the best design to follow ?

[image]

Comment: The "best" design doesn't really mean anything. What specific aspect of the design are you trying to improve? What are your constraints?

Comment: A few opinions: 1) "We want to sell as much electrical components as possible, so we advise option A". 2) "I have 2 transformers and 8 diodes lying around. The TF and diodes cannot handle the currents (in option B), so pick option A" 3) "The diode bridge in option A will quite likely have more losses than option B, so pick B"

Comment: Each led driver needs 1.5A at full load. See [HV9961 led driver design](https://static5.arrow.com/pdfs/2015/10/8/0/7/57/93/mcp_/manual/hv9961db1_fig.1_1.jpg).
Price of component is not a constraint, but board size is. So less component may be better.
In option B, i can upgrade choke TF and the bridge. Is there a risk of  unstability between each driver in option B (noises, down current, etc...) ?